# Can't compile the F# compiler on Windows

Tags: f#

I want compile F# on Windows

my Windows have installed .NET 4.7.2

I run build.cmd, as https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp said

got error:

```
Can't find property "PositionalBinding" for class "System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute" at 
C:\code\fsharpfromgithub\fsharp\eng\build.ps1:17 char 15
+ [CmdletBinding <<<< (PositionalBinding=$false)]
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

I create a VM, install only .net core 2.2, but got same error

Is some one got same error? How to fix it, Thanks!

Comment: You should follow the devguide: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is more about PowerShell than .NET Framework or Core. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletbindingattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

You might try installing this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/

Or updating your Windows SDK at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk